# Creating an efficient function to fit a dataset

Tags: math, interpolation, data-fitting

Basically I have a large (could get as large as 100,000-150,000 values) data set of 4-byte inputs and their corresponding 4-byte outputs. The inputs aren't guaranteed to be unique (which isn't really a problem because I figure I can generate pseudo-random numbers to add or xor the inputs with so that they do become unique), but the outputs aren't guaranteed to be unique either (so two different sets of inputs might have the same output).

I'm trying to create a function that effectively models the values in my data-set. I don't need it to interpolate efficiently, or even at all (by this I mean that I'm never going to feed it an input that isn't contained in this static data-set). However it does need to be as efficient as possible. I've looked into interpolation and found that it doesn't really fit what I'm looking for. For example, the large number of values means that spline interpolation won't do since it creates a polynomial per interval.

Also, from my understanding polynomial interpolation would be way too computationally expensive (n values means that the polynomial could include terms as high as pow(x,n-1). For x= a 4-byte number and n=100,000 it's just not feasible). I've tried looking online for a while now, but I'm not very strong with math and must not know the right terms to search with because I haven't come across anything similar so far.

I can see that this is not completely (to put it mildly) a programming question and I apologize in advance. I'm not looking for the exact solution or even a complete answer. I just need pointers on the topics that I would need to read up on so I can solve this problem on my own. Thanks!

TL;DR - I need a variant of interpolation that only needs to fit the initially given data-points, but which is computationally efficient.

Edit:
Some clarification - I do need the output to be exact and not an approximation. This is sort of an optimization of some research work I'm currently doing and I need to have this look-up implemented without the actual bytes of the outputs being present in my program. I can't really say a whole lot about it at the moment, but I will say that for the purposes of my work, encryption (or compression or any other other form of obfuscation) is not an option to hide the table. I need a mathematical function that can recreate the output so long as it has access to the input. I hope that clears things up a bit.

Comment: Interpolation by its nature is computationally expensive. You might want to consider using regression instead.

Comment: 1. Does the function you're looking for have to fit those data points exactly? Or can it simply be an approximation?
2. If you're never going to feed it an input that isn't in your data set, why do you need the function at all? The purpose of interpolation is to get intermediate values.

Comment: @Steve - Can regression give me a function that will reproduce the outputs exactly or just approximate them? I edited my question to clarify that I need the precision.

Comment: @tskuzzy - I've edited my question to give a little more detail, but basically I do need it to be exact and unfortunately I can't really use the table itself.

Comment: @bridgeburner: If you need exact numbers, then you will need to use interpolation, and there's really no way to get around it.

I can't really see interpolation taking up less space than the exact values -- just look them up from some data store so that you don't need to hardcode anything. It'll also be faster. (:

Comment: Unless you know the form of the underlying function (linear, quadratic, sinusiod...), then what you are asking is impossible from an information-theoretic standpoint.  In general, there is no more efficient encoding of an arbitrary (unconstrained) function than a lookup table.  (Because any possible encoding only represents one function...  And any representation smaller than a lookup table admits fewer encodings than a lookup table.)

Comment: @Nemo: I was afraid of that...I knew I wouldn't reach the efficiency of a look-up table, but I was hoping to to find something that would be considered reasonably efficient as opposed to calculating the 8000th power of a 4-digit number (like I'd need to do with the polynomial interpolation for example). But you're right of course, and it only makes things worse that there isn't really an underlying function that this data-set represents. I might be bashing my head against a brick wall here, time to re-evaluate my options. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one idea.  Make your function be the sum (mod 2<sup>32</sup>) of a linear function over all 4-byte integers, a piecewise linear function whose pieces depend on the value of the first bit, another piecewise linear function whose pieces depend on the value of the first two bits, and so on.

The actual output values appear nowhere, you have to add together linear terms to get them.  There is also no direct record of which input values you have.  (Someone could conclude something about those input values, but not their actual values.)

The various coefficients you need can be stored in a hash.  Any lookups you do which are not found in the hash are assumed to be 0.

If you add a certain amount of random "noise" to your dataset before starting to encode it fairly efficiently, it would be hard to tell what your input values are, and very hard to tell what the outputs are even approximately without knowing the inputs.

Comment: I like the idea! I don't think I can use this directly, but it's a good starting point for some productive exploration. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't impose any restriction on the function (continuous, smooth, etc), you could simply do a piece-wise constant interpolation:

[image: Piece-wise constant interpolation]

or a linear interpolation:

[image: Linear interpolation]

I assume you can figure out how to construct such a function without too much trouble.

EDIT: In light of your additional requirement that such a function should "hide" the data points...

For a piece-wise constant interpolation, the constant intervals should be randomized so as to not reveal where the data point is. So for example in the picture, the intervals are centered about the data point it's interpolating. Instead, you might want to do something like:

```
[0 , 0.3) -> 0
[0.3 , 1.9) -> 0.8
[1.9 , 2.1) -> 0.9
[2.1 , 3.5) -> 0.2
etc
```

Of course, this only hides the x-coordinate. To hide the y-coordinate as well, you can use a linear interpolation.

Simply make it so that the "pointy" part isn't where the data point is. Pick random x-values such that every adjacent data point has one of these x-values in between. Then interpolate such that the "pointy" part is at these x-values.

Comment: I looked at both of these before I posted the question actually. Piece-wise is essentially the same as having a look-up table so its a no go. Linear requires a line equation for each interval - and there are bound to be a lot so I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: I just read your edit and modified my answer accordingly. And you say that it requires a lot of equations, but really there's no other way to do it for so many data points. Even if a polynomial interpolation was computationally feasible, you'd still end up with a 150,000-degree polynomial.

Comment: Yeah, I've been thinking about it and I might have to abandon this approach in favor of something else. I might be completely wrong (again), but I'm currently trying to see if I can train a neural network to approximate my desired function as closely as possible. Thanks though!

Comment: You might want to look into genetic algorithms if you're planning to go down the approximation route. I remember writing a program which used a genetic algorithm to do regression with relative success. I'm hardly an expert in the subject though so I'm not sure what's the best way to go about solving your problem.

Comment: Upvote for genetic algorithms. That's one of the options I'm exploring right now.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a huge [Lookup Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table) full of unused entries. It's the brute-force approach, having an ordered table of outputs, ordered by every possible value of the input (not just the data set, but also all other possible 4-byte value).

Though all of your data would be there, **you could fill the non-used inputs with random, arbitrary, or stochastic** (random whithin potentially complex constraints) data. If you make it convincing, no one could pick your real data out of it. If a "real" function interpolated all your data, it would also "contain" all the information of your real data, and **anyone with access to it could use it to generate an LUT as described above**.

LUTs are lightning-fast, but very memory hungry. Your case is on the edge of feasibility, requiring (2^32)*32= 16 Gigabytes of RAM, which requires a 64-bit machine to run. That is just for the data, not the program, the Operating System, or other data. It's better to [have 24, just to be sure](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/01/24-gigabytes-of-memory-ought-to-be-enough-for-anybody.html). If you can afford it, they are the way to go.

Comment: Your approach is a good way to hide the 'real' data as it were, but my goal is actually more steganographic in that I'm trying to avoid static data as far as possible in favor of something that's almost completely code. I've realized since posting my question though that information theory basically dictates that even storing the coefficients of any parametric equations I use will be a significant amount of 'static' data. Foiled by reality again! :)