# Formula for custom number scale conversion

Tags: algorithm, math

I have a very specific number scale that I need a formula to convert. Unfortunately - it isn't something obvious (to me) and I'm not sure how to approach it.

The original scale is a 0-35+, and I need to convert it to a 100-0 scale.

The numbers are laid out as follows, where the left needs to change to the right.

```
100.00% 0.00%
35.00%  14.99%
34.99%  15.00%
25.00%  24.99%
24.99%  25.00%
15.00%  34.99%
14.99%  35.00%
10.00%  49.99%
9.99%   50.00%
5.00%   74.99%
4.99%   75.00%
1.00%   89.99%
0.99%   90.00%
0.00%   100.00%
```

Any pointers?

Comment: Is there a predictable pattern here? These numbers seem pretty arbitrary.

Comment: There is no clear pattern visible here! I guess it is kinda impossible to provide a suitable number system!!!

Comment: Luckily, we don't need much rhyme or reason to model arbitrary functions, so long as we're willing to put up with a few assumptions.  [Have you considered piece-wise interpolation?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6510981/580412)

Comment: I second the motion for piecewise interpolation.

Comment: Looking into piecewise interpolation - not really following how I can apply it to this problem (been a bit since I did this kind of math...) - The numbers really are somewhat arbitrary (especially the 100% input number - the numbers I am working off of note > 35, but don't give a top limit. But essentially, working to take a 35-0 scale and convert it to 15-100 with some handling for inputs greater than 35 rolling down to 0 in the output.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a sequence in the given set of inputs and outputs and made a formula. Here is the algorithm of that formula:

```
res=24.99
if(input <= 15)
res+=25-input;
if(input <= 10)
res+=25-input;
if(input <= 5)
res+=25-input+5;
if(input <= 1)
res+=25-input-9;
if(input <= 0)
res+=10;
if(input>=35)
res+=25-input;
if(input>=40)
res+=25-input;
if(res>100)
res=100
if(res<0)
res=0;
```

Comment: Close - though that pattern breaks down when the input is below 14.99 (try the formula for an input of 10 - it should come out to 49.99, but it comes out to 39.99 instead. Also - an input of 0 needs to be 100, but that is a simple switch). This gives me a great direction - thank you for that.

Comment: @ross_ritchey you may change minor values and get the desired output.

Comment: 25-input + 24.99 works for all inputs greater than 14.99 but this addition method falls far short with inputs below 14.99. it tends to create large jumps in the result.